# Add Servlet/jsp to a gradle project

Tags: jsp, servlets, gradle, configure

Is it possible to add servlet and jsp to a gradle project? How can i configure my gradle project to act this way? I am struggle with this. I find many useful links on internet but they were not relevant.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is Gradle's `WAR` plugin. Applying this plugin will allow you to build web applications with servlets, JSPs, web.xml etc.

Please, use this [documentation paget](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/war_plugin.html)